# knitr::include_graphics() can't find file if knitr root.dir is changed

Tags: r, knitr

`knitr` allows you to change the directory in which code chunks are evaluated by changing the `root.dir` option

````
```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '~/Project')
```
````

This can also be changed in the global options of RStudio

[image]

The directory options (with advantages and disadvantages) are well described in the [R Markdown Cookbook: Chapter 16.6 The working directory for R code chunks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html).

I have the following file tree

```
├── Project
    ├── Fig
    │   └── Fig1.png
    └── Rmd
        └── Test.Rmd
```

The R Markdown file `Test.Rmd` looks like this

````
---
title: "Title"
output: html_document
---

```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '~/Project')
```

Now include figure

```{r}
knitr::include_graphics('Fig/Fig1.png')
```
````

Rendering the R Markdown file like this will **not** include the figure.

There are many similar issues described

- [Stack Overflow: knitr::include_graphics() fails with PandocResourceNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68674031/6152316)
- [Github issue: include_graphics() cannot find file when 1) working folder is not where the document is and 2) knit from working folder. #1825](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1825#issue-589665252)
- [knitr::include_graphics() doesn't render figure with `bookdown`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68643668/6152316)

The suggested solution are

Option 1) use `normalizePath()` and set `rel_path = FALSE`

```
knitr::include_graphics(path = normalizePath('Fig/Fig1.png'), rel_path = FALSE)
```

Option 2) use path relative to Rmd file and set `error = FALSE`

```
knitr::include_graphics(path = "../Fig/Fig1.png", error = FALSE)
```

Option 3) use absolute path

```
knitr::include_graphics(path = '~/Project/Fig/Fig1.png', rel_path = FALSE)
```

Is there any better solution? Would it not be possible to fix `knitr::include_graphics()`?